# Checking md5 without looking character by character

Tags: debian, md5

Every time I have to check md5 sums I issue the proper command, and then check character by character to see if they're the same. I think this is far from ideal, the ideal would be to add an option to the command line, including the expected checksum, and then the program itself would tell me if they're the same or not.

In Debian, I'm using md5sum, but I don't see this option in its manual. Does this option exists there, or should I use a different software?

Comment: What do you mean by "character by character"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth [This iso](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download/) has the checksum of 1e77e1c65187884ba79a3bd06b02fc29. So I have to look 1, e, 7, 7, e, 1, c... in both the site and the result of the md5sum.

Comment: But why does that involve explicit "character by character" as opposed to a string comparison?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Because I'm doing it with my eyes! I want to know if there's a software option that will compare the whole string at once. Like `md5sum file.iso --expected '1e77e1c65187884ba79a3bd06b02fc29'`

Comment: Oh :)  Does [this approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum#Check_single_MD5) help?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum#Check_single_MD5):

```
echo 1e77e1c65187884ba79a3bd06b02fc29 my.iso | md5sum -c
```

When `md5sum` is given the `-c` flag, it processes a file containing a list of expected hashes and filenames.  If no file is provided, then it reads these from `stdin`.

Comment: I saw it working, but I still don't get _how_ does it work?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I don't understand how exactly `echo` followed by two parameters (a string and a filename) are merged to be passed through pipe (|) to `md5sum -c`.